# How should I rewrite the beginning of the linked post?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

How should I rewrite the beginning of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-the-function-in-the-description-exist)?

It seems people aren’t commenting since it’s difficult to understand.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe break up the first paragraph, something like this:

Does there exist a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that

1. the graph of $f$ is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and
2. the collection of all the pre-images of each of the subsets of the range of $f$ under $f$, such that the pre-images are non-measurable in the sense of Caratheodory, is a *[non-perfect dense set][1]* in the collection of all subsets of $[0,1]$, and
3. $f$ is non-uniform (i.e. without [complete spacial randomness][2]) in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

I had trouble parsing 2), I don't know whether what I have written conveys what you intended.

Comment: What you’ve written is correct.

Comment: You stated you have trouble parsing 2. What is your interpretation of this?

Comment: The way I wrote it reflects my interpretation. I'd say, you look at the range of $f$ – let's call it $R$; you look at a subset of $R$, let's call it $S$; you look at $T$ defined by $T=f^{-1}(S)$; you insist that $T$ be "non-measurable in the sense of Caratheodory" (I don't know what that means, but that's my problem, not yours); and then you ask that the collection of all such $T$ be a non-perfect dense set in the collection of all subsets of $[0,1]$. I guess it's not clear to me what topology you are putting on the collection of all subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Did you click the link on “non-perfect dense set”. It should lead you to Dave L. Renfro’s answer. Perhaps the topology can be specified there.

Comment: No, I didn't click on the link. I'm not actually interested in the question, I'm just trying to help you get it to where it might be reopened.

Comment: As a last note, I added that $f$ should be “measurable in the sense of caratheodory”? Is the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist) clear or should I make changes.

Comment: I think it reads much better now than it did before, but I'll leave final judgement to those who have expertise in the subject matter.